# Problem saving/getting cookies in MVC 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, cookies

Try to save them like this:

```
HttpCookie latcook = new HttpCookie("latitude", lat.Value.ToString());
                HttpCookie lngcook = new HttpCookie("longitude", lng.Value.ToString());
                Request.Cookies.Add(latcook);
                Request.Cookies.Add(lngcook);
```

Everything has a value, and the code steps through without error.

Then immediately after those are set, I refresh my page and step through this:

```
HttpCookie latcook = Request.Cookies.Get("latitude");
                HttpCookie lngcook = Request.Cookies.Get("longitude");
```

The `latcook` and `lngcook` variables have names, but no values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding your cookies to the request object.  They should be added to the *response*:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(latcook);
Response.Cookies.Add(lngcook);
```

Cookies added to the response are returned to the user's browser via a series of `Set-Cookie` HTTP headers.   They are then subsequently sent back (upon the next request) via the `Cookie` HTTP header. (You should be able to watch this happen using Firebug, etc.)   Ultimately, this header will be parsed and populate the `Request.Cookies` collection.